# Mapping Key-Value pair using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to this platform. I am trying to solve a problem using JavaScript that has the following input and expected output. I would appreciate if anyone could help with how to achieve it. Thanks!

Input:

```
{ 
  {"name":"Jon","age":24}, {"name":"Kim","age":31} 
}
```

Expected output:

```
{ "Jon":24, "Kim":31 }
```

Comment: You will get better answers if you show us the code you have written to solve the problem and describe the issue you are having with that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JSON is supposed to be an array we do need to reduce.

Here is the shortest version

```js
const arr = [
  { "name": "Jon", "age": 24 }, 
  { "name": "Kim", "age": 31 }
];

console.log(arr.reduce((acc, {name, age}) => (acc[name] = age, acc), {}))
```

If not, then you need to get a better input

Answer (score 0):

The input is invalid `json`, if it's an `array`, try [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [ {"name":"Jon","age":24}, {"name":"Kim","age":31} ];

const res = data.reduce((acc,item) => {
  const { name, age } = item;
  acc[name] = age;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```